# want to make the selected radios as default value when form submit is called

Tags: forms

my form

```
$form['area']['check'] = array(
    '#type' => 'radios',
    '#options' => array(
        'search' => t('search'),
        'search_user' => t('search_user'),
        'search_tags' => t('search_tweets'),
        'search_name' => t('search_name'),
    ),
    '#default_value' => 'search_tweets',
```

### and form_submit is below

```
$_SESSION['check'] = $form_state['values']['check'];
if(isset($_SESSION['check'])){
  form_set_value($form['area']['check'], $radio_value, $form_state);
  form_set_value($form['area']['check'], 'search_user', $form_state);
  $string_replace = str_replace(" ", "-", $results->name);

  $form_state['rebuild'] = true;
  // drupal_goto('tweets-by-tags/' . $string_replace);
  $form_state['redirect'] = array('tweets-by-tags/' . $string_replace);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Please pay attention to code formatting, what you posted was just not readable. Also please add a better description of what you want to achieve and how you current approach fails. See the [Help center](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help) to find more information about how to write great questions.

Answer (score 1):

Your declaration of the default value is wrong.

You should use the option's key in the `default_value` of your radios element.
So you would end up with :

```
$form['area']['check'] = array(
  '#type' => 'radios',
  '#options' => array(
    'search' => t('search'),
    'search_user' => t('search_user'),
    'search_tags' => t('search_tweets'),
    'search_name' => t('search_name'),
  ),
  '#default_value' => 'search_tags',
);
```